# Partial derivatives in thermodynamic and constant conditions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $f$ be a multivariable function $f(x^{i}), i=(1,2,3....)$ its partial derivative is:

$ \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{i}} \right)\bigg|_{x^{j \ne i}=const}$

Can I define an equation where its left side implies $x^{j}$ constant and its right side implies a partial derivative of $x^{j}$?

For instance if $x^{j}$ is the temperature (T) and $x^{i}$ is the pressure (p) (where C is a constant and g is a temperature function) then if I say that the partial derivative of f with respect to temperature is a measurable property (U) being:

$ \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} \right)\bigg|_{T} =U= C + \left( \frac{\partial g(T)}{\partial T} \right)$

Does this make sense? Because to measure U I should leave temperature constant but the practical case implies a change in temperature:

[Practical case: *Heat of reaction and Van't Hoff realation*

$r_{T,p} = \left( \frac{\partial H}{\partial \xi} \right)_{T, p} : r_{T,p} = -RT^{2}\frac{\partial }{\partial T}ln K(T,p)$

After integration

$ln\frac{K_2}{K_1}=-\frac{\Delta H}{R} \left( \frac{1}{T_2} - \frac{1}{T_1}\right) $ ]

Comment: Yes, this is just a physicist notation to indicate what are the other variables considered when doing the partial derivatives, they are not really "constants".

Comment: @LL3.14 So What are they?

for instance the temperature definition implies that V and chemical composition () must be constant hence Does it implie that chemical reaction with a change in volume has no temperature to be measurable?

Comment: There are just variables in the mathematical point of view. Imagine you take the partial derivative of $x^2y^2$ with respect to $x$. Then you do *as if $y$ is a constant when you take your derivative* and you get $2xy^2$. But $y$ is still a variable. For example you could then take a partial derivative with respect to $y$ now, so of course it is not a fixed value ...